# Error while registering node in selenium grid

Tags: selenium-grid

I am getting below error while starting node for selenium grid-

```
Default driver org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:  [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}]
```

does not match with current platform: MAC

My local system that is hub contains MAC and FIREFOX

Below the configuration of my node(VM).My scripts are on my local machine that is hub-

```
    {
        "class": "org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest",
        "capabilities": [
          {
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "version": "25.0.1",
            "maxInstances": 1,
            "platform" : "LINUX"
         }
        ],
    }
```

Please suggest needful.

Answer (score 0):

There might be two obvious errors:

1. In your code, you state `Platform` as `Linux` but you are running on **MAC**
2. The same might be on the node setup. If you run node on mac and then request for Internet Explorer on Windows, it will be simply skipped, hence there is no node running on Windows...